# What is weird "/.$" or ".$" in the react key name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to put the change children with some element like div in react component. and I found lot of way to do that.

The problem is when I create a holder element over the child and give right key to the holder but the react added some weird character to the key and change my key.

I want to use `react-grid-layout` but the keys should be the same of the layout config props. so, I need to react stop changing the keys.

Here is my code:

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { index, children } = this.props;

                // Sample1: /.$
        const childWithHolders1 = React.Children.map(children, child => (
            <div key={"holder" + child.key}>
                holder key: {"holder" + child.key}
            </div>
        ));

        const realReactKeys1 = childWithHolders1.map(divComp => divComp.key + "\n");

                // Sample2: .$ (just pass number to the key)
        const childWithHolders2 = React.Children.map(children, child => (
            <div key={child.key}>
                holder key: {child.key}
            </div>
        ));

        const realReactKeys2 = childWithHolders2.map(divComp => divComp.key + "\n");
        
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Sample 1</h2>
                {childWithHolders1}
                <br />
                <h3>The Real React Keys: </h3>
                <pre>{realReactKeys1}</pre>
                
                <br /><h2>Sample 2</h2>
                {childWithHolders2}
                <br />
                <h3>The Real React Keys: </h3>
                <pre>{realReactKeys2}</pre>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { index } = this.props;
        return (
            <p>Child Index: {index}</p>
        )
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>What is weird "/.$" or ".$" in the react key name ???</h2>
                <Main>
                    <Child key="1" index="1" />
                    <Child key="2" index="1" />
                    <Child key="3" index="1" />
                </Main>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: These are React internal implementation details, it shouldn't really matter for your code.

Comment: @DrewReese I know but It's matter for `react-grid-layout`, I should send children with the same keys that I defined in the layouts prop.

Comment: I don't believe any ui libs are going to use the key as `props`, key is used for React internally. Maybe you should create a prop for that particular usage instead of abusing key. Or search around the github issues in that libs. You probably missed something from doc.

Comment: @Yunhai As I thought before this is problem with the `react-grid-layout`, I saw that code and find this library using the keys of the children components. They use the keys for match the configs of layouts with the children. As you mention, They should not use the keys for such thing but It's make a lot of problem for my codes.

I try to read react github code but I could not find anything related to these key changing.

Ref:

https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout/blob/master/lib/ReactGridLayout.jsx

Comment: The lib definitely utilized the key, maybe you should check out all the alternatives to see if key prop is a must use for this kind of ui libs to work. If so, what I would do is to reconstruct the `main` and `child` structure. Make it more direct without using `react.childen.map` to see if the problem still persists. Fallback to simple case even official cases to check which functions cause your problem.